# undefine reference to tcmalloc public API

Tags: c++, malloc, tcmalloc, gperftools

I've cloned google-perf git tree.

```
> ./autogen.sh
> ./configure --enable-frame-pointers --prefix=/usr/
> make
> sudo make install
```

All steps above were successful. I can see the header files in /usr/include/gperftools/tcmalloc.h etc

My program

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <gpertools/malloc_extension.h>
 #include <iostream>

 int main()
 {
 const unsigned int tcmalloc_stats_buf_len_ = 32768;
 char tcmalloc_stats_buf[tcmalloc_stats_buf_len_];

 MallocExtension::instance()->GetStats(tcmalloc_stats_buf,
                                      tcmalloc_stats_buf_len_);
 printf("%s ",tcmalloc_stats_buf);
 fflush(stdout);
 }
```

Compilation

```
g++ -ltcmalloc my_prog.c -o my_prog
my_prog.cc: undefine reference to MallocExtension::instance
```

If I comment out GetStats line then the compilation is working fine. So I assume it's linking with tcmalloc. However when I try to access API it gives me an error.

What could be the problem? Any ideas perhaps?

Comment: Can you provide us with the error message you're getting? So we can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

From Aliaksey Kandratsenka

Try moving -ltcmalloc to the end. Especially in static linking mode, 
linker is *only* looking at library objects at the time it is 
processing it in order given in command line and it only pulls symbols 
known to be needed *at that time*. This is not widely known "gotcha" 
about static linking that sometimes makes necessary to specify libs 
twice or more times.

This shouldn't affect dynamic linking but I think I've heard some 
distros (ubuntu perhaps) are overly creative with their linker 
configurations (and require -Wl,--no-as-needed or something like 
that).